# Есть папка, хочу проверить все папки и файлы до конца и потом вернутся обратно

Tags: java, файлы, io

Есть папка, хочу пройтись по всем элементам, и если это папка, то зайти в неё и продолжать пока не закончатся элементы.Если это файл, то проверить название файла и если подходит, то удалить. Как можно сделать?

```
File directory = new File("C:\\Users\\Admin\\Desktop\\Something\\directory");
    File[] files = new File("C:\\Users\\Admin\\Desktop\\Something\\directory").listFiles();
    // Graph g = new Graph
    try{
        for(File thisFile : files){
            if(thisFile.isFile()) {
                String data = thisFile.getName();
                int FileDay = Integer.parseInt(data.substring(data.length() - 6, data.length() - 4));
                int FileMonth = Integer.parseInt(data.substring(data.length() - 9, data.length() - 7));
                int FileYear = Integer.parseInt(data.substring(data.length() - 14, data.length() - 10));

                if (FileYear * 12 + FileMonth <= year * 12 + nowMonth - month + 1) {
                    thisFile.delete();
                }
            }
        }
    }
    catch(NullPointerException e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Код работает только для одной заданной папки, но нужно чтобы он проверял папки внутри папок. Думал через Depth First Search как-то сделать, но не получилось.

Comment: Используйте рекурсию.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Можно так

```
    public static void main(Strnig[] args) {
        chkDir(new File("C:\\Users\\Admin\\Desktop\\Something\\directory"));
    }

    private void chkDir(File dir){
        for (File f : dir.listFiles()){
            if(f.isDirectory()){
                chkDir(f);
            }else{
                chkFile(f);
            }

        }
    }

    private void chkFile(File f){
        ...
    }
```